# How to print the array?

Tags: c, arrays, printing, multidimensional-array

```
int main() {  
  int my array[3][3] =
    10, 23, 42,    
    1, 654, 0,  
    40652, 22, 0  
  };  

  printf("%d\n", my_array[3][3]);  
  return 0;
}
```

I am not able to get the array to print.. Any ideas why? I am a beginning programmer so any words of advice are appreciated.

Comment: Is some of the code missing? It looks like you're missing an opening bracket on the array, as well as an _ in the my_array declaration

Comment: just one word of advice: you should specify the language you are coding in so as to better identify a proper solution :)

Comment: Oh, and you should tell us the error you get, because there's a lot of room for errors in that code ;)

Comment: Big hint:  Array indexes start at 0.  `my_array[3][3]` is trying to get the 4th cell in the 4th row of your array.  What's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What you are doing is printing the value in the array at spot [3][3], which is invalid for a 3by3 array, you need to loop over all the spots and print them.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This will print it in the following format

```
10 23 42
1 654 0
40652 22 0
```

if you want more exact formatting you'll have to change how the printf is formatted.

Comment: If you are programming in c++ you can also use `cout` instead of `printf`

Comment: @trev9065 true but he used `printf` and didn't have a language stated when I answered so I stuck with `printf`.

Answer (score 13):

There is no .length property in C.  The .length property can only be applied to arrays in object oriented programming (OOP) languages.  The .length property is inherited from the object class; the class all other classes & objects inherit from in an OOP language.  Also, one would use .length-1 to return the number of the last index in an array; using just the .length will return the total length of the array.

I would suggest something like this:

```
int index;
int jdex;
for( index = 0; index < (sizeof( my_array ) / sizeof( my_array[0] )); index++){
   for( jdex = 0; jdex < (sizeof( my_array ) / sizeof( my_array[0] )); jdex++){
        printf( "%d", my_array[index][jdex] );
        printf( "\n" );
   }
}
```

The line (sizeof( my_array ) / sizeof( my_array[0] )) will give you the size of the array in question.  The sizeof property will return the length in bytes, so one must divide the total size of the array in bytes by how many bytes make up each element, each element takes up 4 bytes because each element is of type int, respectively. The array is of total size 16 bytes and each element is of 4 bytes so 16/4 yields 4 the total number of elements in your array because indexing starts at 0 and not 1.

Comment: This wouldn't work if the array is not square since `jdex` is looping using the size of the outer array and not the inner one.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have a typo on your array, it should read:

```
int my_array[3][3] = {...
```

You don't have the `_` or the `{`.

Also `my_array[3][3]` is an invalid location. Since computers begin counting at `0`, you are accessing position `4`. (Arrays are weird like that).

If you want just the last element:

```
printf("%d\n", my_array[2][2]);
```

If you want the entire array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < my_array[i].length; j++)
    printf("%d ", my_array[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{  
  int i,j;
  int my_array[3][3] ={10, 23, 42, 1, 654, 0, 40652, 22, 0};
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
  {
       for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
       {
         printf("%d ", my_array[i][j]);
       }
    printf("\n");
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the array like you print a 2D list in Python:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j;
  int my_array[3][3] = {{10, 23, 42}, {1, 654, 0}, {40652, 22, 0}};
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      if (i == 0) {
          printf("[");
      }
      printf("[");
      for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
         printf("%d", my_array[i][j]);
         if (j < 2) {
             printf(", ");
         }
      }
    printf("]");
    if (i == 2) {
        printf("]");
    }

    if (i < 2) {
        printf(", ");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output will be:

```
[[10, 23, 42], [1, 654, 0], [40652, 22, 0]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to print an entire array and not just printing the contents of the array by iterating through them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Only a few lines of code. Don't be afraid of the pointers (to beginners).

```
void PrintArray(uint8_t *data_arr, uint8_t data_length)
{
    while (data_length--)
    {
        printf("0x%02x ", *data_arr);
        *data_arr++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Chang the printf() statement according to your use.
If you need to print as char:

```
printf("%c", (char)*data_arr);
```

For decimal values:

```
printf("%d ", (uint8_t) *data_arr);
```