# Coding Tic Tac Toe in C with only If statements

Tags: c, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

So the past week I've been attempting to learn some C, I was giving an exercise to code a really simplistic version of tic tac toe.

I have been asked:

> 1. Prompt two users to enter a ‘naught’ or a ‘cross’ respectively into one of the nine positions on the tic, tac, toe grid
> 2. After all 9 inputs have been made display the grid
> 3. To make it simpler: only when all 9 grid positions have been entered figure out if there is a winner (you can do this with a few ‘if’ statements)
>      .

I'm told this can be done with a few `if` statements, so far I have only learnt up to `if`'s, including the basic `int`, `char`, `float`, `double`, ect.

So, what I'm not truly grasping in how to only use `if` statements to check if:

1. the position is already taken, if it has prompt the user to try again or place the current persons naught or cross in that position.
2. keep track of the positions the two users enter, so I know which position each of the two users they have entered to check those positions if its empty or not.

I feel like I am somewhat over thinking this but I am unsure, if anyone has got any help that'd be great.

This is what I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char board[9]; 
    int num;
    printf("Today we are playing a game of Tic Tac Toe\n");
    printf("To play the game you need to line up 3 of the same type 'x's or o's' in a line to win\n");
    printf("Before we start, whoever wants to be 'X' starts first, and whoever wants to be 'O' starts second\n");
    printf("The board looks like this\n");
    printf("%d%c%d%c%d\n", 1, 124, 2, 124, 3);
    printf("%d%c%d%c%d\n", 4, 124, 5, 124, 6);
    printf("%d%c%d%c%d\n", 7, 124, 8, 124, 9);
    printf("Lets begin");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'X';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'O';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'X';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'O';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'X';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'O';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'X';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'O';
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 - 9 ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    board[num] = 'X';
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Could I also ask that all answers be kept to only using `if` statements as that is as far as I am up too, and it is how the exercise is meant to be completed, although probably this is ten times easier with for/while and arrays.
Thank you!

Comment: You really don't need `spot0`, `spot1` and so on. You can simply create an array `int spot[9];`

Comment: `if((temp = 1)){
        spot0 == "X";` --> `if((temp == 1)){
        spot0 = 'X';`

Comment: thanks ForceBru and BLUEPIXY for providing me with helpful information. arash kordi, you obviously don't understand what this site is about, I'm here to learn more by seeing what mistakes i have made and what I can learn to improve the code..

Comment: @Collwyr Also, You don't need Your spots to be `int` type, You can use `char`, because You're only storing characters and not some really large numbers.

Comment: @Collwyr If You're using array to store Your spots then, You have to use `spot[0]`, `spot[1]` etc. instead of `spot0`, `spot1` etc.

Comment: @jacajack, nice spot, i added them in from the above suggestions and i forgot to add that extra into the code. thanks.

Comment: @Collwyr Actually, I started developing Your code and I added and improved some things. Whole thing gets just nicer when You're using loops and functions, You should consider that. Do You want to see what I go so far?

Comment: Collwyr you still have an `if((temp=2)` there. Deadly mistake (because it's *syntactically* correct), `==` is for testing equality, `=` is for assignment, as @BLUEPIXY pointed out already.

Comment: @Andras Deak, yeah thank you for the point out, i did relook over my code now and i still miss things :( thanks for pointing it out tho.

Comment: @Collwyr, another thing: your `if` checks `(temp == 2) && (temp!= 1)`. But if `temp == 2` (and this is evaluated first), then surely `temp != 1`, so this is redundant. And you do miss a lot of things:)

Comment: @Andras Deak, yeah I've changed mine up now, I've just updated mine, I think it's working, I just need to figure out how to make it print in a tic tac toe format. I don't know how to print out an array, don't suppose you do?

Comment: @Collwyr, a bit of formatting with `printf` would do (see e.g. [printing an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9726975/5067311). However, your code doesn't check whether a given site has been occupied earlier (but you would need a loop to keep asking for input until a new site is supplied). And you should check in the end who wins;)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that gradually editing the question with a solution is incompatible with Stack Overflow's Q&A design. If you think the question can later benefit other users, you should add the final version as an answer (and mark it as accepted) and restore the original question. If you feel like it is only useful to you in the foreseeable future, you could also consider deleting the question eventually. I know we're not done yet, just wanted to give you a heads up:)

Comment: @andras Deak, okey, I wasn't aware regarding the editing process, i'll be more careful next time, thanks for the heads up. yes you are correct, my code doesn't check whether a position has been occupied or not and you are right it would require a for loop, which i'm not fully sure I could write properly right now. I am trying to check if a user is a winner or not but I'm not really "sure" how to go about making the if's to do so.

Comment: For the record, you'd need a `while` loop:) And yes, deciding the winner is non-trivial, even if you don't restrict yourself to `if`s. I'm not sure how I'd do that efficiently (i.e. without manualy checking all 8 possible winning configurations). Another thing: someone might have won before the end. If the game keeps going, you might end up with an apparent tie (having more than 1 winning line). So you should define a function checking for a winner, and calling that in each game step...

Comment: @AndrasDeak - technically you do not need a `while` loop. The board has a fixed size, therefore can be played with a series of `if` statements.

Comment: @owacoder, how would you treat if I was a moron and kept requesting site 1, even though that's already filled? Of course if we assume that the user is infallible (...), we don't need a while;)

Comment: In that case, you might as well abort the game. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 #define ROWS 3
 #define COLUMNS 3
 #define PLAYER_ONE 'X'
 #define PLAYER_TWO 'O'

void board();//calling class required by C
int checkForWinner();//calling class required by C
char tic_tac_toe[ROWS][COLUMNS] =
    {
        { '1', '2', '3'},
        { '4', '5', '6'},
        { '7', '8', '9'}
    };
int main()
{

    int isGameOn=1, currentPlayer=1, pick;
    char checked;

    do
    {
        board();
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer % 2) ? 1 : 2;
        printf("Player %d, pick a number: ",  currentPlayer);
        scanf("%d", &pick);
        checked = (currentPlayer == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';
        isGameOn = checkForWinner();
        if(pick == 1 && tic_tac_toe[0][0] == '1'){
            tic_tac_toe[0][0] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1)break;
        }else if(pick == 2 && tic_tac_toe[0][1] == '2'){
            tic_tac_toe[0][1] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 3 && tic_tac_toe[0][2] == '3'){
            tic_tac_toe[0][2] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 4 && tic_tac_toe[1][0] == '4'){
            tic_tac_toe[1][0] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 5 && tic_tac_toe[1][1] == '5'){
            tic_tac_toe[1][1] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 6 && tic_tac_toe[1][2] == '6'){
            tic_tac_toe[1][2] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 7 && tic_tac_toe[2][0] == '7'){
            tic_tac_toe[2][0] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 8 && tic_tac_toe[2][1] == '8'){
            tic_tac_toe[2][1] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }else if(pick == 9 && tic_tac_toe[2][2] == '9'){
            tic_tac_toe[2][2] = checked;
            if(isGameOn == 1){break;}
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid moved");
        }
        isGameOn = checkForWinner();
        if(isGameOn == 1){
            printf("***************************************\n");
            printf("The winner is player %d\n", currentPlayer);
            printf("***************************************");
            break;
         }
        currentPlayer++;
    }while(isGameOn == -1);
    board();

    return(0);
}
/*Functions*/

    /*Board display*/
    void board()
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%c\t %c\t %c\n", tic_tac_toe[0][0], tic_tac_toe[0][1], tic_tac_toe[0][2]);
        printf("%c\t %c\t %c\n", tic_tac_toe[1][0], tic_tac_toe[1][1], tic_tac_toe[1][2]);
        printf("%c\t %c\t %c\n", tic_tac_toe[2][0], tic_tac_toe[2][1], tic_tac_toe[2][2]);

    }
    /*Checking for winner*/
    int checkForWinner()
    {
        /*checkign vertical line*/
        for(int col=0; col<COLUMNS; col++){
            int row=0;
            if(tic_tac_toe[row][col] == tic_tac_toe[row+1][col] && tic_tac_toe[row+1][col] == tic_tac_toe[row+2][col]){
                return 1;
            }
        }
        /*checking horizontal line*/
        if(tic_tac_toe[0][0] == tic_tac_toe[0][1] && tic_tac_toe[0][1] == tic_tac_toe[0][2]){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(tic_tac_toe[1][0] == tic_tac_toe [1][1] && tic_tac_toe[1][1] == tic_tac_toe[1][2])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(tic_tac_toe[2][0] == tic_tac_toe [2][1] && tic_tac_toe[2][1] == tic_tac_toe[2][2])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(tic_tac_toe[0][0] == tic_tac_toe[1][1] && tic_tac_toe[1][1] == tic_tac_toe[2][2])/*diagonal*/
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
```